# Receiving int is invalid expression errors

Tags: c#

I have a simple program that takes a user input, tries to parse the input as an integer, then rounds PI to the value of the input.  However, I'm getting two errors.  One that says that `int` is an invalid expression, and another that says that the variable that holds the input value doesn't exist in the current context.  Can anyone explain to me why these errors would be appearing and how to fix them?

```
using System;

namespace PiToDecimalPlaces{
    class Program{
        public static void Main(){
            //Checks to see if the user input can be parsed into an int data type.  If it can, return the places variable.
            int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int places);
            Console.WriteLine(Round(places));
        }
        public static decimal Round(int places){
            //Converts the PI value to a decimal, then rounds PI to the number of decimal places given by the user, and returns PI to the number of decimal places.
            return Math.Round((decimal)Math.PI, places);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are using C# 7 features but are not using a C# 7 compiler.

Comment: Ah, ok.  So I just need to update VS?

Comment: Choose your Language version to C# 7 as `int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int places);` is the feature introduced in c# 7.0

Comment: @Robert Yes, you need to update to Visual Studio 2017

Comment: In the meantime, you could `int places; int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out places);`

Answer (score -2):

i am using vs2017 and use code like this

Console.WriteLine("{0}",Round(places));

and it will print integer value